# Pin Disqus Comments?

Tags: disqus

Is there a way to "pin" or leave a thread at the top of the list? Almost like you see on community forums where important or common threads always stay at the top?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this as well. From what I could find you can not pin a specific comment to always be at the top of the comment thread. You can however set the order of the comments to be more "Recent" or "Best". Using the "Best" sort option might give you somethings close to what you are looking for though.